# Mongoose: select documents that have reference to another document

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'd like to make an Item with Comments in my MongoDB\Mongoose project.
As this is my first project with MongoDB, I have a strange question:

I need an Item document like this

```js
var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String
});
```

And I need comments for this item like this:

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
text: String,
itemId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' },
});
```

And I **do not want** to keep comment Ids in my Item document like this:

```
var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
comments: [ {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' } ]
});
```

So how should I call the model `Item` to get all `comments` for this item if I know only `Item.name` value? Can I do it with `populate()` in a single mongoose request or i have to make two requests (first to get `Item` to lookup `_id`, second to get `Comments` where `itemId == Item._id` ?

Or maybe I am doing this completely wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [virtual population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals).

```
itemSchema.virtual('comments', {
    ref: 'Comment', // The model to use
    localField: '_id', // Find comments where `localField`
    foreignField: 'itemId', // is equal to `foreignField`
});
```

Then if you have the **document** `item`, you would do

```
item.populate('comments').execPopulate().then(() => {
    console.log(item.comments);
});
```

We use [execPopulate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-execPopulate) because you only want to populate comments.

If you have the **model** `Item`, you would do

```
Item.findOne(...).populate('comments').exec((err, item) => {
    console.log(item.comments);
});
```